# Parser Error cxf-beans.xml no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:endpoint'

Tags: maven, cxf, m2eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://sampleService.viasat.com/"
id="sampleserviceinterfcae" implementor="com.viasat.sampleservice.SampleServiceInterfcaeImpl"
    wsdlLocation="wsdl/sampleserviceimplementation.wsdl" endpointName="tns:SampleServiceImplementationPort"
    serviceName="tns:SampleServiceImplementationService" address="/SampleServiceImplementationPort">
<jaxws:features>
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
</jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

I'm using Maven to build the Application. After `mvn clean` and `mvn install` I deploy the application in Tomcat after which I'm getting the following error:

> `Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/cxf-beans.xml] is invalid;`
>
> `nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:endpoint'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your spring configurations looks alright. So the only reason I could think of is that you are missing one of those dependencies in your classpath (most likely `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make sure that you have them in your `pom.xml` and it should work.

Comment: +1 In our case, the same was being excluded while building our project. Added the dependency explicitly while we are work on finding the root cause.